# why Json Dictionary is Giving the response in nsdata(Bytes) always.How can i Get the Dictionary from web service

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

In this i am sending the header and Add perameters to hitting the web service. the problem is after hitting the web service controller is not going in to success part sometimes. if it is hitting properly then it will return the result in bytes.
This is My code::

```
 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager =[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setTimeoutInterval:300];
manager.requestSerializer.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData;

//giving the correct format to json
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
token=[parameters valueForKey:@"token"];
if(token == nil  || [token isEqual:[NSNull null]]){
    token=[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]dictionaryForKey:@"LoginWebData"]valueForKey:@"token"];
}else{
    token=[parameters valueForKey:@"token"];
}
//set the header do http request
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",token]forHTTPHeaderField:@"token"];
[manager POST:[BaseURLString stringByAppendingString:methodName] parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){

    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    UserDict=responseObject;
    [self.TableviwSideMenu reloadData];
}
      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
          NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
          [self showAlert: [error localizedDescription]];
      }];
```

Comment: can you show the result of NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

Comment: Add this into your code NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:(NSData *)responseObject options:kNilOptions error:&jsonError];
NSLog(@"JSON: %@", json);

Comment: @Maddyヅヅ - no need of Serilize the responseObject ,its already type of Dictionary or Array, we can use what we need

Comment: can u please  reffer me best approach For hit the Web Service with AfNetworking.I have tried Your Code It Is Not responding.@Maddy And @Anbu.Karthik.Thanks for Replying me.

Comment: Because Which Code I m using Its Not Responding Properly sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

> the AFNetworking will do the serialization for you and the responseObject will most likely be either a NSArray or NSDictionary object do like

```
   [manager POST:[BaseURLString stringByAppendingString:methodName] parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){

    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
       if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    NSArray *responseArray = responseObject;
       UserDict=responseArray;
    /* do something with responseArray */
} else if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    NSDictionary *responseDict = responseObject;
     UserDict=responseDict;
    /* do something with responseDict */
}
    if (UserDict.count>0)
     [self.TableviwSideMenu reloadData];

}
      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
          NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
          [self showAlert: [error localizedDescription]];
      }];
```

Answer (score 0):

The AFNetworking framework and its delegate will handle everything. You will get responseObject in NSDictionary.

```
  -(void)Request{
    [self.Request_coursecomplete setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    self.Request_coursecomplete = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:sendSMSURL];
    self.Request_coursecomplete.delegate = self;


    //will try second time
    [self.Request_coursecomplete setNumberOfTimesToRetryOnTimeout:2];

    [self.Request_coursecomplete setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];

    NSTimeInterval timeOutSecs = 60000;

    [self.Request_coursecomplete setTimeOutSeconds:timeOutSecs];
    [self.Request_coursecomplete startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{

    NSString *receivedString = [request responseString];

    NSLog(@"json string: %@",receivedString);

    NSDictionary *d = [receivedString JSONValue];
}
```